# Debugging colissionCount on Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, kubernetes-statefulset

I have a StatefulSet in Openshift that keeps restarting, but only on a single node. I don't see anything in PODs logs. In `/var/log/message`s I see only messages that container is restarting, volume is unmounted etc and some more cryptic `'error: Container is already stopped'` and `'cleanup: failed to unmount secrets: invalid argument'`.

However, when I look and Yaml for StatefulSet I see the following:

```
status:
  collisionCount: 1
  currentReplicas: 1
```

I suppose this is what is the real cause.
But how can I find out what has generated that collision?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`StatefulSets` internally perform an snapshot of the data via `ControllerRevisions` and [generate a hash for each version](https://godoc.org/k8s.io/api/apps/v1#ControllerRevision).

What the `collisionCount` indicates is that the `ControllerRevision` hash collided, likely due to an [implementation issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/61998#issuecomment-403955359).

You can try to rule this out by getting the controller revisions:

`$ kubectl get controllerrevisions`

Since this is an internal mechanism in the object, there is little to do other than recreate the object to generate new hashes that don't collide. There is a [merged PR](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/66882) that suggests that newer versions shouldn't face this issue. However, [it might be the case](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/61998#issuecomment-512631430) that you're running a version without this patch.

Comment: Oh, well, I've got 2 ControllerRevisions for the same revision, when I've deleted one, the StatefulSet stopped restarting. It seems to be the issue.

Comment: My version is GitVersion:"v1.11.0+d4cacc0".

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `kubectl describe pod` to look up the events?